# Facebook Login App Review requires you to show App using item BEFORE item is approved. How to solve this chicken-or-egg conundrum?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I'm developing a Facebook Login for a website (using the Facebook PHP SDK 3.2.3 since the server is running PHP 5.3).

The website requires several items of information from Facebook Login to complete the registration and profile creation of new users logging in through Facebook, and the majority of those items need to be approved by Facebook.

However, several of the items I requested were **not** approved.

Here is the Feedback from Facebook regarding why they weren't approved:

> Your screencast **doesn't show how this permission is used in your app**,
>   and we weren't able to reproduce the permission on our end either.
>   Please upload a new screencast and update your submission notes before
>   you resubmit. Learn more about making and submitting a screencast.

Further below it says:

> **We need to see your app using user_about_me** so we can see that it
>   doesn't violate our policies. Upload a video screencast walkthrough
>   using any method, (even recording with your phone).

How can I show Facebook the website using `user_about_me` (or any other unapproved item) **before** Facebook approves that item?

My brain is in an infinite loop about this and it can't break free.  HELP!

Comment: The reviewers use accounts that can be asked for any permission without review, same as all accounts with a role in your app.

Comment: @CBroe:  But how do I show them how that permission is used if I can't access that permission?  What am I supposed to take a video screencast of exactly if they haven't granted me the permission yet?

Comment: You can access the permission. You can ask anyone that has a role on the app for any permission even if they are not approved

Comment: @WizKid:  So if my Facebok account is listed as one of the Administrators of the App, I can actually access all permissions (even unapproved ones) as long as I "login" to the website through Facebook using my account?

Comment: How else do you think developers are supposed to test their apps?

Comment: @CBroe:  That's why I asked my question, because I could not figure out how you can show FB how the permissions are used BEFORE they grant you those permissions.  It's the entire point of my question, because I didn't know that the Devs get full access from the start.  They should really make that clearer!  Can someone please add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reviewers use accounts that can be asked for any permission without review - same as all accounts with a role in your app can.

Users that are listed as Admin, Developer or Tester can be asked for any permission at any time, reviewed or not - so that you can actually *develop* and *test* your app, *before* you submit it for review.

---

This is mentioned in the App Development FAQ - [My app is only used by a small number of people, who are all listed in the Role section of the App Dashboard - do I need to go through Login Review?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921)

> - No, it does not have to be reviewed. If your app is only used by a very limited number of people - for example, to use the Facebook for Wordpress plugin to publish to your profile - it's completely normal to list them all as having different roles in your app's dashboard. They can be listed as Admins, Developers or Testers
> - Some background on this: To enable you to develop and fully test your app, anyone listed in the Role section of your app's dashboard can be granted any permission necessary to test without review by Facebook. The purpose of Login Review is to protect the experiences of regular people who may interact with your app. Directly adding a small set of well-known people directly to your app is used for software development, testing and small application deployments.

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried testing this, and it breaks the App. I tested fetching an unapproved item from users that are Administrators and Testers, and was given a warning by Facebook that unapproved items were being included, and when I clicked to continue, it took me back to the homepage of the website instead of the page of the website that requested Facebook authorization.  As soon as I removed the unapproved items, I tested it again, and it took me back to the correct page of the site that had requested the authorization with the details of the Facebook user.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You should of course set up two separate environments, and not mix production with development code ... a subdomain to run the new codebase on is the common approach.

Comment: That's not the problem, the problem is that if I add unapproved items, Facebook redirects the user back to the homepage.  If I remove the unapproved items, then Facebook correctly redirects the user back to the page where they came from on the site.  In other words, the addition of unapproved items is making Facebook behave differently and breaking the App as the user needs to return to the page they came from to process their FB data.  Why is Facebook behaving differently when unapproved items are added despite the user having a role in the App?

Comment: The warning is normal; app developers are informed that they need to submit for review, before they can ask normal users for the permissions. Are you sure the redirect is issued by Facebook, and not from your scripts at your end? Without any code it's hard to tell what might go wrong where.

Comment: It cannot be a coding issue because the coding is identical except that I added 1 unapproved item.  There is nothing on the coding end that would redirect the user to the homepage instead of to the page containing the Facebook Login.  In fact, it is Facebook that controls the redirect since the user gets redirected to Facebook when they click the FB Login button and are then supposed to be redirected back to the page they came from.  Except when I simply add 1 unapproved item, Facebook sends them back to the homepage.  This is with the PHP SDK 3.2.3.  Any ideas?

Comment: _"This is with the PHP SDK 3.2.3"_ - you couldn't find anything older? Current is v5. Sorry, but with code that old you're on your own, debugging-wise. If I had to guess, then I'd say it probably goes wrong (at least) at the point where it exchanges the `code` for an access token, because the API return format for that changed between API(!) version v2 and v4, and I am not sure if the version 3 PHP SDK was even maintained at that point any more.

Comment: I had to use the PHP SDK 3.2.3 because the server is running PHP 5.3, unfortunately.  It's still very bizarre how adding an unapproved item is making Facebook and/or the SDK behave *differently* (in my case, by changing which page it redirects to).  I just don't know how I'm going to get the screencast Facebook needs to approve the items if I can't get the Website app to work with the unapproved items.  Is there a way to contact Facebook support?

Comment: Not really. You could try the FB Developers Group, but I doubt you'll hear something different there - if you want to keep using that old SDK, you will likely have to debug the issue yourself, or get a more experienced developer on board. Fact is, for review they expect a working app, otherwise it will get rejected straight away.

Comment: I narrowed the redirecting issue down to an OAuthException error where I was incorrectly using the permission name (user_about_me) as the field (about).  I fixed it and now it works.  Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

Seems that now you need some Page Access Token to get it to work in DEV mode in order to make a valid Review. I found this on one of the FB bug threads:

- Make sure your app is in dev-mode and you are administrator of the
  facebook page you want to access using the api
- Go to the Graph Api. Explorer Select your app and choose 'Get Page Access Token' in the 'Get token' dropdown. Agree with the questions in the popup that opens
- Select the access token in the 'Page access tokens' dropdown that belongs to the page from step 1. Copy the 'access token' field value and use it in your code

The funny thing is that this is now working everywhere, even for FB users who don't have any roles in you app or page.

Bravo Facebook for making this so frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set test users and No, not talking about the users you can set pn the same page as admin and developer. Go to roles section in left menu of the developer section.
Add new users -> set a nr of new users, add the permissions you want to test.

When you login as one of the test users (created in roles) go to settings,
check the app and you'll see the permissions set for this user.
Yet to figure out why these don't show up when first logging into the app, but that would be another question.